# how to convert nested json array into multiple json records in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Hi I have json string contain 3 nested json arrays and i need to split those 3 arrays into json records in python

I try below code to :

the three nested array is :
'**questionGroups**' which contain another nested json array '**questions**' which contain another nested json array '**answerOptions**'

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_data = """
{
    "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z",
    "questionGroups": 
    [
        {"id": "12",
         "name": "Welcome", 
         "type": "questionGroup", 
         "manualWeight": false, 
        "questions": 
        [
            {"id": "123", "text": "Respond with welcome", "helpText": "", "type": "multipleChoiceQuestion", "naEnabled": true, 
            "answerOptions": 
                    [{"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, {"id": "847y59", "text": "1", "value": 2}],
                    "isKill": false, "isCritical": false},
            {"id": "234", "text": "Respond with hello", "helpText": "", "type": "ChoiceQuestion", "naEnabled": true,
            "answerOptions": [{"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, {"id": "sdkmfkj", "text": "1", "value": 2}], 
            "isKill": false, "isCritical": false}
        ]
        },
        {"id": "13",
        "name": "hi", 
        "type": "questionGroup", 
        "manualWeight": false, 
       "questions": 
       [
           {"id": "33123", "text": "Respond with welcome", "helpText": "", "type": "multipleChoiceQuestion", "naEnabled": true, 
           "answerOptions": 
                   [{"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, {"id": "847y59", "text": "1", "value": 2}],
                   "isKill": false, "isCritical": false},
           {"id": "67234", "text": "Respond with hello", "helpText": "", "type": "ChoiceQuestion", "naEnabled": true,
           "answerOptions": [{"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, {"id": "sdkmfkj", "text": "1", "value": 2}], 
           "isKill": false, "isCritical": false}
       ]
       }
    ]
}
"""


data = json.loads(json_data)

print(pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['questionGroups'],meta=[
    'id', 'name','modifiedDate'],record_prefix='questionGroups_').explode('questionGroups_questions').to_json(orient='records', lines=True))
```

the output is only 4 records ( it only split 2 arrays ('questionGroups' and 'questions') but 'answerOptions' did not split into reocrds ):

```
{"questionGroups_id":"12","questionGroups_name":"Welcome","questionGroups_type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false,"questionGroups_questions":{"id":"123","text":"Respond with welcome","helpText":"","type":"multipleChoiceQuestion","naEnabled":true,"answerOptions":[{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},{"id":"847y59","text":"1","value":2}],"isKill":false,"isCritical":false},"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z"}
{"questionGroups_id":"12","questionGroups_name":"Welcome","questionGroups_type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false,"questionGroups_questions":{"id":"234","text":"Respond with hello","helpText":"","type":"ChoiceQuestion","naEnabled":true,"answerOptions":[{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},{"id":"sdkmfkj","text":"1","value":2}],"isKill":false,"isCritical":false},"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z"}
{"questionGroups_id":"13","questionGroups_name":"hi","questionGroups_type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false,"questionGroups_questions":{"id":"33123","text":"Respond with welcome","helpText":"","type":"multipleChoiceQuestion","naEnabled":true,"answerOptions":[{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},{"id":"847y59","text":"1","value":2}],"isKill":false,"isCritical":false},"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z"}
{"questionGroups_id":"13","questionGroups_name":"hi","questionGroups_type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false,"questionGroups_questions":{"id":"67234","text":"Respond with hello","helpText":"","type":"ChoiceQuestion","naEnabled":true,"answerOptions":[{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},{"id":"sdkmfkj","text":"1","value":2}],"isKill":false,"isCritical":false},"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z"}
```

i want to convert the 3 nested list to raws in json format but it only split the 2 arrays ('questionGroups' and 'questions') and for 'answerOptions' did not split into records

**so what i excepted is the output to be 8 records but the output is only 4 records because the 'answerOptions' did not split into records**

is there are a way to split also the inner array '**answerOptions**' ? or only i can split the top tow nested json array ?

**the excepted output is 8 records like below :**

```
    {"questionGroups_questions_id":"123","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"multipleChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"123","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"multipleChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"847y59","text":"1","value":2},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"234","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"ChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"234","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"ChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"sdkmfkj","text":"1","value":2},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"33123","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"multipleChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"33123","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"multipleChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"847y59","text":"1","value":2},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"67234","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"ChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"12345","text":"0","value":0},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id":"67234","questionGroups_questions_text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups_questions_helpText":"","questionGroups_questions_type":"ChoiceQuestion","questionGroups_questions_naEnabled":true,"questionGroups_questions_answerOptions":{"id":"sdkmfkj","text":"1","value":2},"questionGroups_questions_isKill":false,"questionGroups_questions_isCritical":false,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups_manualWeight":false}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you expect?

Comment: @JonSG i edit the question and include the the excepted output is 8 records to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

You can add all paths to record_path and net the meta path:

Code:

```
print(pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    record_path=[
        "questionGroups",
        "questions",
        "answerOptions"
    ],
    meta=[
        "id", "name", "modifiedDate",
        ["questionGroups", "id"], ["questionGroups", "name"], ["questionGroups", "type"],
        ["questionGroups", "manualWeight"],
        ["questionGroups", "questions", "isKill"], ["questionGroups", "questions", "isCritical"],
        ["questionGroups", "questions", "id"], ["questionGroups", "questions", "text"],
        ["questionGroups", "questions", "helpText"],
    ],
    record_prefix="meta."
).to_json(orient="records", lines=True))
```

Output:

```
{"meta.id":"12345","meta.text":"0","meta.value":0,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"123","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"847y59","meta.text":"1","meta.value":2,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"123","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"12345","meta.text":"0","meta.value":0,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"234","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"sdkmfkj","meta.text":"1","meta.value":2,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"12","questionGroups.name":"Welcome","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"234","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"12345","meta.text":"0","meta.value":0,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"33123","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"847y59","meta.text":"1","meta.value":2,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"33123","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with welcome","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"12345","meta.text":"0","meta.value":0,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"67234","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
{"meta.id":"sdkmfkj","meta.text":"1","meta.value":2,"id":"1","name":"test1","modifiedDate":"2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z","questionGroups.id":"13","questionGroups.name":"hi","questionGroups.type":"questionGroup","questionGroups.manualWeight":false,"questionGroups.questions.isKill":false,"questionGroups.questions.isCritical":false,"questionGroups.questions.id":"67234","questionGroups.questions.text":"Respond with hello","questionGroups.questions.helpText":""}
```

Comment: but in this case i only get the values inside the 'answerOptions' , i except the output to include all json tags

Comment: see edit for meta path nesting

Comment: Close, but something not quite right about `"questions.id":"12"` in your output as I think those should be the ids of the individual questions like "33123" and at the moment look like they are the group id repeated

Comment: @JasonBaker thanks for your help , is there are way to rename them in way more better that questionGroups.id ?

Comment: @Code you marked this as correct, but please validate this results `"questions.id":"12"` for every row vs your expected `"questionGroups_questions_id":"123"`...

Answer (score 0):

I would just manually walk your json loaded as a dictionary via `json.load()` and assemble each row:

```py
results = [
    {
        "questionGroups_questions_id": question["id"],
        "questionGroups_questions_text": question["text"],
        "questionGroups_questions_helpText": question["helpText"],
        "questionGroups_questions_type": question["type"],
        "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": question["naEnabled"],
        "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": answer_option,
        "questionGroups_questions_isKill": question["isKill"],
        "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": question["isKill"],
        "id": json_data["id"],
        "name": json_data["name"],
        "modifiedDate": json_data["modifiedDate"],
        "questionGroups.id": question_group["id"],
        "questionGroups.name": question_group["name"],
        "questionGroups.type": question_group["type"],
        "questionGroups_manualWeight": question_group["manualWeight"]
    }
    for question_group in json_data["questionGroups"]
    for question in question_group["questions"]
    for answer_option in question["answerOptions"]
]

print(len(results))

import json
for result in results:
    print(json.dumps(result))
```

That should give you:

```
8
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "123", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with welcome", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "multipleChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "12", "questionGroups.name": "Welcome", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "123", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with welcome", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "multipleChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "847y59", "text": "1", "value": 2}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "12", "questionGroups.name": "Welcome", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "234", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with hello", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "ChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "12", "questionGroups.name": "Welcome", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}        
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "234", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with hello", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "ChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "sdkmfkj", "text": "1", "value": 2}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "12", "questionGroups.name": "Welcome", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}      
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "33123", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with welcome", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "multipleChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "13", "questionGroups.name": "hi", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false} 
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "33123", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with welcome", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "multipleChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "847y59", "text": "1", "value": 2}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "13", "questionGroups.name": "hi", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "67234", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with hello", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "ChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "12345", "text": "0", "value": 0}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "13", "questionGroups.name": "hi", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}
{"questionGroups_questions_id": "67234", "questionGroups_questions_text": "Respond with hello", "questionGroups_questions_helpText": "", "questionGroups_questions_type": "ChoiceQuestion", "questionGroups_questions_naEnabled": true, "questionGroups_questions_answerOptions": {"id": "sdkmfkj", "text": "1", "value": 2}, "questionGroups_questions_isKill": false, "questionGroups_questions_isCritical": false, "id": "1", "name": "test1", "modifiedDate": "2023-10-17T16:20:09.091Z", "questionGroups.id": "13", "questionGroups.name": "hi", "questionGroups.type": "questionGroup", "questionGroups_manualWeight": false}
```

You can write this out with `json.dump()`